# Besides dim regularization, what are the advantages of Euclidean QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wick-rotation, dimensional-regularization

Initially, I saw Wick rotation as a useful trick to apply dimensional regularization, but then I learned about instantons and how they only exist in Euclidean Yang-Mills.
Also, I heard that path integrals are "more well-defined" in Euclidean spacetime.
What are the other advantages?

Comment: Have you studied up on [Lattice Gauge theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_gauge_theory) and how it is simulated on a computer?

Comment: Euclidean QFT can be used as an auxiliary model that helps you formulate the physical QFT in Minkowski space time. Look up Osterwalder-Schreder reconstruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very good question!

Besides some technical advances, that you already presented in question, first of all, very important to realise statement:

> **The Osterwalder-Schrader** reconstruction theorem states that correla-
> tors in a reflection positive Euclidean QFT can be analytically continued
> to give Wightman functions that are tempered distributions on Minkowski
> space $R^{d−1,1}$.

See, for example, section 3 of [Lorentzian methods in conformal field theory
Slava Rychkov](https://sites.google.com/view/lorentz-cft). Nowadays, these ideas extensively studied in CFT, see also [this](https://gitlab.com/davidsd/lorentzian-cft-notes/-/blob/master/TASI-Lorentzian-CFT.pdf). Main idea is very illustrative:

> Unitary Lorentzian CFTs are related to reflection-positive Euclidean
> CFTs by Wick rotation. This is the **Osterwalder-Schrader reconstruction
> theorem**. Thus, in
> principle, everything about a Lorentzian CFT is encoded in the usual CFT
> data (operator dimensions and OPE coefficients) that can be studied in
> Euclidean signature. However, many observables, and many constraints
> on CFT data are deeply hidden in the Euclidean correlators.

Also, it's very important to realise, that Euclidean QFT are used in condensed matter physics. For example, it is useful tool for describing of critical phenomena.For introduction, one can consult
[David Tong: Lectures on Statistical Field Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html).